# What is the complexity of computing the p-values for a multivariate hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Are there efficient approaches to compute p-values of samples drawn from a multivariate hypergeometric distribution?  Specifically, how does the complexity grow as a function of the "urn size" and the number of different "colors" of balls within the "urn"?

Comment: This seems to me to be borderline for MO. But I can't dismiss it right away. You may not get many answers though.

Comment: Perhaps your local friendly computation/statistical Q&A forum?

Comment: @david Thanks, I'll move on if there are no takers but MO seemed like it *might* be suitable.

Comment: Since a lot of people here aren't _au fait_ with p-value computation algorithms, would you provide some examples? That may help to anchor the question a bit.